# How much does the message size affect RabbitMQ Producer sending to Queue?

Tags: performance, rabbitmq, producer

So I've been learning as I go with RabbitMQ and I have servers and producer set up; not caring about consumer until i get this fixed. So im collecting my String data over 30 seconds, concatenating them, and sending them as 1 big string; average size is 1180000 bytes. And what I'm experiencing is that the messages take a minimum of 10 minutes to appear in the queue; and up to 30 minutes!

My question is does the size of the message impact the time it takes to get into the queue that much? Or does that not matter and I must be doing something else wrong...

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have sent some huge strings, and never had it take long. What language and client are you using to send the string?

Comment: Using Java, and using amqp 3.3.5. And the goal of course would be for it to send within 5 seconds or so. I have no idea if that is a pipe dream or not.

Comment: essentially going off of the tutorials.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18353898/rabbitmq-message-size-and-types and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842096/can-rabbitmq-be-used-for-avatars-in-a-chat-server?lq=1, note, that if message is not persistent it will reside in memory.

Comment: First I would ask you how are you measuring if the message is in the queue or not.

Apart from that. 10 minutes for a message delivery is not normal. If that's really the case, there's something wrong with your code or your installation most probably.

Comment: [This ancient blog post from RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2012/04/25/rabbitmq-performance-measurements-part-2/) mentions that message size kills the service's send message rate, and the benchmark suggests the service's performance is tied to the test system's data transfer rate.