# Maximum message size for RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

What is the maximum size that a message can be when publishing to a RabbitMQ queue (pub/sub model) ?

I can't see any explicit limits in the docs but I assume there are some guidelines.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RabbitMQ message size and types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18353898/rabbitmq-message-size-and-types)

Answer (score 13):

I was doing comparison between **Amazon Queue Service** and **RabbitMQ** or other streaming+messaging platforms like kinesis, kafka. As Amazon Queue Service only supports min `2^10 bytes(1 Kilobytes)` - max `2^18 bytes (256 Kilobytes)`, similarly kinesis has size limits too. (Don't know why?)

Anyway In theory **AMQueueProtocal** would handle `2^64 bytes`. So, even for a huge message, RabbitMQ might work in a single broker, definitely taking minutes/hours to persist but would or might not in a cluster of brokers. If the `message transfer time between nodes (60seconds?) > heartbeat time between nodes`, it will cause the cluster to disconnect and the loose the message.

[This thread is useful -> Can RabbitMQ handle big messages?](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.networking.rabbitmq.general/14665)

### References

http://grokbase.com/t/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-discuss/127wsy1h92/limiting-the-size-of-a-message

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.networking.rabbitmq.general/14665

http://rabbitmq.1065348.n5.nabble.com/Max-messages-allowed-in-a-queue-in-RabbitMQ-td26063.html

https://www.rabbitmq.com/heartbeats.html