# Send a file through rabbitmq

Tags: php, python, symfony, rabbitmq

I have a python client and a symfony backend. They can send and receive messages using rabbitmq.

I use [rabbitmq symfony bundle](https://github.com/php-amqplib/RabbitMqBundle) on my backend.

I send an id of a php entity to the python client which get i through my api, do some work (heavy work) and store the result in a zip file. I want to send this zip file through rabbitmq. Is it possible? The file is really large (like 5mo)

If it's possible how can i do it ? (in an efficient way)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would not recommend using a message broker to send files.

I would store the zip file somewhere s3, nfs, disk and add the URI as a resource pointer in the message.

More information about messages queues and message sizes can be found here:
[Maximum message size for RabbitMQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23336038/maximum-message-size-for-rabbitmq)

Comment: that's what i did. Thank you