# Rabbitmq message size is larger than configured max size

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, queue, message-queue, amqp

I got error when sending message to queue:

```
Channel closed by server: 406 (PRECONDITION-FAILED) with message "PRECONDITION_FAILED - message size 180760424 is larger than configured max size 134217728"
```

How can I increase this value 134217728 (128 mb) ?

UPD: SOLVED max_message_size(default=134217728) in rabbitmq.conf

Comment: I think here's the answer to your question [RabbitMQ message size and types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18353898/rabbitmq-message-size-and-types)